# How to return a resource style from a converter?

Tags: c#, wpf

Suppose that I need to set a different `Foreground` based on the value of the current item of a `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="5">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <Text="{Binding Match5}" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                         <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                               <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Match5, Converter={StaticResource NameToBrushConverter}}"/>
                               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Match5, Converter={StaticResource ForegroundConverter}}"/>
                               <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Match5, Converter={StaticResource NameToWidthConverter}}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                  </TextBox.Style> 
             ...
```

I created a converter:

```
public class ForegroundConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var input = value as string;

        if (input.Contains("-"))
            return "MaterialDesignBody";

        return "White";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

now when the item does not contain `-` the white foreground is setted, but when the value contains `-` I need to return a `DynamicResource` provided by `MaterialDesignInXaml`, but I get this error in the output console:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 6 : 'DynamicValueConverter' converter failed to convert value 'MaterialDesignBody' (type 'String'); fallback value will be used, if available. BindingExpression:Path=Match1; DataItem='LatestFiveMatchRow' (HashCode=87685); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Foreground' (type 'Brush') FormatException:'System.FormatException: Invalid Token.

any idea or hint? Thanks.

Comment: @Clemens very sorry Clemens for some reason I didn't reiceved a notification on so, I'll try your answer, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that

```
return "White";
```

only works due to built-in automatic type conversion. There is a BrushConverter class registered as TypeConverter for the target property or its type, i.e. Brush:

```
[TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(BrushConverter))]
[LocalizabilityAttribute(LocalizationCategory.None, Readability = Readability.Unreadable)]
public abstract class Brush : Animatable, IFormattable
```

This TypeConverter (which must not be confused with a Binding's IValueConverter) is capable of converting well-known Brush names like "White" to their equivalent in the `Brushes` class, i.e. `Brushes.White`. However, it can't convert "MaterialDesignBody". You must perform a resource lookup and return the appropriate Brush resource yourself:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value.ToString().Contains("-"))
    {
        return (Brush)Application.Current.FindResource("MaterialDesignBody");
    }

    return Brushes.White;
}
```